# Flying London to Amman mid-May and returning Aqaba-Amman-London. Can I bring laptop on return flight?

Tags: uk, airport-security, electronic-items, event-based-effects, jordan

I'm a UK citizen, and will presumably be affected by the additional security theatre recently announced. I'm flying for a short holiday in Jordan this May, but I'll be returning via a domestic flight from Aqaba connecting with a direct flight to London at Amman.

1. Will I be able to stay air-side at Amman?
2. If so, will I be able to bring my laptop in the cabin, given that I'll have gone through security for the domestic flight at Aqaba, not at Amman itself?

Comment: 1. As I remember at Amman you are (always) bused directly to a very small domestic bag reclaim hall, which is only used for the shuttles from AQJ. You then exit landside and you need to go through passport control and security as though you originate from AMM. Jordan's domestic security is not to the same standard as international security. By the way AQJ is a really tiny airport, bring a book or turn up immediately before departure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update:
As you found yourself, [official information](https://www.gov.uk/hand-luggage-restrictions/electronic-devices-and-electrical-items) is now online (bolding mine):

> Inbound flights to the UK from Turkey, Lebanon, Jordan, Egypt, Tunisia, and Saudi Arabia
> You must put all phones, tablets or laptops in your hold luggage if they are larger than:
>
> - 16cm in length
> - 9.3cm in width
> - 1.5cm in depth (or thickness)
>
> > For example, you can take an iPhone 7 Plus, Samsung Galaxy 7 Edge, Samsung Galaxy Note 3, LG G3 or Sony Xperia Z2 as hand luggage.
>
> **This also applies to:**
>
> - any items you buy at duty free in the airport
> - **connecting flights via these countries, even if your journey started elsewhere.**
>
> You can still bring hairdryers, straighteners, travel irons, electrical shavers and e-cigarettes as hand luggage.

Old post:
Little official information is out so far and I cannot answer your question 1), but for 2)
**you will not be able to bring your laptop in the cabin.**

Source: [OneMileAtATime on the topic](http://onemileatatime.boardingarea.com/2017/03/21/uk-electronics-ban/), itself sourced on [Tweets by Sky News](https://twitter.com/SkyNewsBreak/status/844220296605257729?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw&ref_url=http%3A%2F%2Fonemileatatime.boardingarea.com%2F2017%2F03%2F21%2Fuk-electronics-ban%2F).

Comment: I guess they'll have an additional search of bags for connecting passengers then? Or will they know I'm connecting when I go through security at Aqaba and stop me there? Or is this new security measure just going to be done on the honour system?

Comment: Ah, just found this official source which backs up what you're saying: https://www.gov.uk/hand-luggage-restrictions/electronic-devices-and-electrical-items

Comment: @Muzer There will be extra at-gate security for your London-bound flight. How you got to the gate will be irrelevant.

Comment: Cheers for the help, everyone! i'll mark this as accepted in a little while.

Comment: Many thanks! I've been on the trip now, and they did indeed have additional security checks at the gate in Amman.

One thing I didn't realise until I got to Heathrow on my outward trip is that the ban also includes certain accessories to laptops and phones, including (to my understanding) portable USB battery packs. These also can't be carried in the hold, because of concerns around fires, so they can't be carried at all. I had one on me when I read this. In the end, I decided to put it in my hold luggage, (correctly) theorising that they'd be unlikely to spot it and care enough.